# Перенести логику построения графиков из Excel в MatPlotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, matplotlib

У меня есть две функции:

```
sales_new = Sales_old + Sales_old * (1-row["Vector_price"]/LastPrice)*Kэ
revenue_new = (Sales_old + Sales_old * (1row["Vector_price"]/LastPrice)*Kэ)*row["Vector_price"]
```

При построении графиков в Excel и выбрав встроенную функцию - "По вспомогательной оси" графики нормируются по одной некой шкале.
Теперь я пытаюсь перенести построение графиков в matplotlib, но не понятно как их нормировать по аналогии как это делает Excel

Кто то встречался с такой проблемой?

Comment: ну так вы свой код покажите. у вас вопрос странный. вам нужен список людей, которые встречались с такой проблемой или решение этой проблемы?

Answer (score 1):

В библиотеке Matplotlib можно использовать вторую ось (вспомогательную ось) для нормализации графиков по аналогии с Excel. Вот как это можно сделать:

1. Создайте два набора данных для графиков: sales_new и revenue_new. Предположим, что они уже есть у вас в виде списков или массивов данных.
2. Импортируйте необходимые модули:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
```

3. Создайте базовое графическое окно и ось:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
```

4. Постройте первый график `sales_new` на основной оси:

```py
ax.plot(sales_new, label='Sales')
```

5. Скопируйте ось ax второй раз и назовите ее ax2. Он будет представлять вспомогательную ось:

```py
ax2 = ax.twinx()
```

6. Постройте второй график revenue_new на вспомогательной оси:

```py
ax2.plot(revenue_new, color='red', label='Revenue')
```

7. Нормализуйте шкалу на вспомогательной